# Optimize Average of Averages SQL Query

Tags: sql, hadoop, query-optimization, impala

I have a table where each row is a vendor with a sale made on some date.

I'm trying to compute average daily sales per vendor for the year 2019, and get a single number. Which I think means I want to compute an average of averages.

This is the query I'm considering, but it takes a very long time on this large table. Is there a smarter way to compute this average without this much nesting? I have a feeling I'm scanning rows more times than I need to.

```
-- Average of all vendor's average daily sale counts
SELECT AVG(vendor_avgs.avg_daily_sales) avg_of_avgs
FROM (
        -- Get average number of daily sales for each vendor
        SELECT vendor_daily_totals.memberdeviceid, AVG(vendor_daily_totals.cnt) 
avg_daily_sales
        FROM (
                -- Get total number of sales for each vendor
                SELECT vendorid, COUNT(*) cnt
                FROM vendor_sales
                WHERE year = 2019
                GROUP BY vendorid, month, day
        ) vendor_daily_totals
        GROUP BY vendor_daily_totals.vendorid
) vendor_avgs;
```

I'm curious if there is in general a way to compute an average of averages more efficiently.

This is running in Impala, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just do the calculation in one shot:

```
SELECT AVG(t.avgs)
FROM (
    SELECT vendorid,
           COUNT(*) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT month, day) as avgs
    FROM vendor_sales
    WHERE year = 2019
    GROUP BY vendorid
) t
```

This gets the total and divides by the number of days.  However, `COUNT(DISTINCT)` might be even slower than nested `GROUP BY`s in Impala, so you need to test this.

Comment: Marking this as correct since it is the clean version I was looking for, although I realized after testing `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is indeed a lot slower than nested `GROUP BY`s in Impala.

Comment: Added an edit with the average of averages which is what was desired in the question. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: When running `$ time impala -f nested_group_by.sql` I got an average of 41 sec. When running `$ time impala -f count_distinct.sql` I got an average of 746 sec. Important to note: this impala dataset uses daily partitions (on fields `year`, `month`, and `day`).

Comment: @Wassadamo . . . Postgres, Hive, and Redshift have problems with `COUNT(DISTINCT)` (performance-wise).  I guess Impala inherited that as well.